# Tensorflow error TF error: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

```py
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 27, in <module>
    import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
  File "C:\Users\ateyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\ateyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Users\ateyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client import pywrap_tf_session
  File "C:\Users\ateyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\pywrap_tf_session.py", line 19, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client._pywrap_tf_session import *
ImportError: SystemError: <built-in method __contains__ of dict object at 0x000002901E7A0630> returned a result with an error set
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 27, in <module>
    import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
  File "C:\Users\ateyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\ateyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Users\ateyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client import pywrap_tf_session
  File "C:\Users\ateyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\pywrap_tf_session.py", line 19, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client._pywrap_tf_session import *
ImportError: SystemError: <built-in method __contains__ of dict object at 0x000001B8DA1705E8> returned a result with an error set
```

Answer (score 4):

Kindly check the C-API version and Numpy version from [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/59aad3cf436691d447e43038e3402500f13cd817/numpy/core/setup_common.py#L43).

The error message suggests that you have a version of Numpy that provides an older version of the C-API. Based on [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/59aad3cf436691d447e43038e3402500f13cd817/numpy/core/setup_common.py#L43), you should upgrade Numpy to 1.20.x or 1.21.x

Please use the following code to upgrade Numpy;

```
pip install numpy --upgrade --ignore-installed
```

or you can use the following;

```
pip install numpy==1.21.6
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c3a64134cd55bd6ed4689d601d5502c7cc0efbab/doc/source/user/troubleshooting-importerror.rst):

A workaround that usually works is to upgrade the NumPy version:

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

---

And possible reasons are:

```
A bad extension "wheel" (binary install) that should use oldest-support-numpy ( with manual constraints if necessary) to build their binary packages.
An environment issue messing with package versions.
Incompatible package versions somehow enforced manually.
An extension module compiled locally against a very recent version followed by a NumPy downgrade.
A compiled extension copied to a different computer with an older NumPy version.
```

Answer (score 2):

Downgrading python from 3.10 to 3.9 worked for me

Answer (score 1):

If the reason of this problem was - like in my case - custom compilation of a reverse dependency of `numpy` (`shap` in my case) against the *latest* version of `numpy` (pre-installed first, before the compilation), followed by `numpy` downgrade by `pip` (due to some other reverse dependency such as `scipy` having a `<=` pin on the version of `numpy`... is a bug), then the solution is to: **reverse the order**:

1. first install `numpy` with all its pre-compiled reverse-dependencies (e.g. `scipy`), and only then
2. perform the compilation of reverse dependency (against the downgraded, i.e. final `numpy` version).