# Got the error when "import tensorflow as tf". Any solutions?

Tags: tensorflow

I got the following error while importing TensorFlow. Is there any way this error can be solved?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Try `pip uninstall tensorflow` and then `pip install tensorflow` if that helps, guess something's wrong with the version.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: [Tfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72018245/tensorflow-error-tf-error-module-compiled-against-api-version-0xe-but-this-vers) has found a solution for this, you can upgrade your `Numpy` version using `pip install numpy --upgrade --ignore-installed`, or you can try `pip uninstall numpy` and then `pip install numpy==1.21.6`